# Flask uWSGI fails with SQL_ALCHEMY_URI set to MySQL db

Tags: mysql, nginx, mysql-python, uwsgi, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a flask app set up according to this [tutorial](http://mattupstate.github.com/python/devops/2012/08/07/flask-wsgi-application-deployment-with-ubuntu-ansible-nginx-supervisor-and-uwsgi.html). The app produces a "uWSGI Error: Python application not found" error when the following line is included:

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql://user:password@localhost/database'
```

Commenting this line out will make the application work (however anything that requires a call to the database fails). The application works properly while running from the built in development server and run from the virtual environment used with uWSGI.

Any help as to why adding this to the flask `app.config` dict is causing the app to fail would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE: Was able to get the app to load using sqlite:

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:////absolute/path/to/tmp.db'
```

The issue seems to be with MySQL, however it does work from the built in flask server, as mentioned above. Any ideas why MySQL could cause this failure is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Solved. The issue was that the virtualenv couldn't import MySQLdb. I removed the virtualenv and recreated it with

```
virtualenv --system-site-packages venv
```

which solved the issue.